# C pointer question for my understanding decimal + decimal[2]

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Hello I have 3 questions / 3 lines of code that i don´t understand.
Would be nice if someone can help me.
My understanding is still not the yellow from the egg.
The questions are commented as //QUESTION:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct trace {
    char *sign;
    int *values;
    struct trace *pN;
};

int main() {
    int decimal[] = {4,2,1};
    char text[]="Word-2!";
    struct trace *pV;
    pV = (struct trace*) calloc(2, sizeof(struct trace));
    pV->pN = pV;
    pV->values = decimal + decimal[2]; // = 2   

    // QUESTION: explanation why decimal + decimal[2] is 2 / what is decimal (not *decimal). 
    // My guess is: decimal[0 + decimal[2]] = decimal[0 + 1] = decimal[1] = 2
    
    (*pV).sign = text + *decimal;  // text + 4  //"-2!";
    *(pV + 1) = pV[0]; // pV[1] = pV[0] = *pV
    ++pV[1].values;         // QUESTION: what does this do?  the ++ in front of pV instead of pV[++1].values
    ++*pV[1].values;        // QUESTION: what does this do?
    printf("%d %s\n", *pV->values, pV->sign);
    printf("%d %s\n",*pV->pN[1].values, pV->pN[1].sign);

    return 0;
}
```

edit: the goal of this is to find out what is being displayed in those 2 printf, which both are:
"2 -2!" and
"2 -2!"

Comment: decimal is an array, decimal[2] is an int. What happens when you add them? Hint: an array used in an expression becomes a pointer.

Comment: Don't guess.  The first question is a pointer assignment, not a value like `2`.  The second increments a pointer.  The third increments the value that a pointer points at.

Comment: @stark that explains why * in front of decimal isn´t needed, thx

Comment: This is a great time to learn to use your debugger. Set a breakpoint on the line you're confused about, run the program, and then inspect the expressions - it should show you both the value and the type.

Comment: @Useless wow you just explained the debugger to me :D I was looking for such an function. Been using it in matlab the whole time without knowing its called debugging. Will try it in eclipse now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good reason you're having trouble understanding that code; it's *obnoxious*.  It's trying to illustrate some of the weirder behaviors of pointers and arrays, but it's done in a way that's excessively "tricky" and difficult to understand.  It mixes and matches array and pointer notation, and it's inconsistent in how it accesses members.  It's also unsafe as hell.  It's a good example of how *not* to write C code.

Before we start, a little syntax cheat sheet:

```
a[i] == *(a + i), therefore
a[0] == *(a + 0) == *a

p->m == (*p).m == (*(p + 0)).m == p[0].m
```

So:

> `pV->values = decimal + decimal[2];`

**TL/DR** - this is setting `pV->values` (which is the same as `(*pV).values`, which is the same as `pV[0].values`) to point to the second element of the `decimals` array; graphically, it would look like this:

```
   +---+        +---+                          +---+
pV:|   | -----> |   | pV[0].sign      decimal: | 4 | decimal[0]
   +---+        +---+                          +---+
                |   | pV[0].values ----------> | 2 | decimal[1]
                +---+                          +---+
                |   | pV[0].pN                 | 1 | decimal[2]
                +---+                          +---+
                |   | pV[1].sign
                +---+
                |   | pV[1].values
                +---+
                |   | pV[1].pN
                +---+
```

It's equivalent to writing

```
pV->values = &decimal[1];
```

In this context, the *expression* `decimal` "decays" from type "3-element array of `int`" to type "pointer to `int`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array (we'll get into why this is later).  To this pointer value we are adding the value stored in `decimal[2]`, which is `1`:

```
pV->values = decimal + 1;
```

Adding 1 to a pointer yields a pointer to the next *object* of the pointed-to type, which is not necessarily the next byte; if the address of `decimal[0]` is `0x8000` and an `int` is 4 bytes wide, then the result of the addition above is `0x8004`, *not* `0x8001`.

> `(*pV).sign = text + *decimal;`

TL/DR - this sets `pV->sign` to point to the `"-"` character of the `text` string; `*decimal` is the same as `decimal[0]`, which contains the value `4`, so the above is equivalent to

```
(*pV).sign = &text[4];
```

By this point in the program, we have the following situation:

```
   +---+        +---+                            +---+
pV:|   | --+--> |   | pV[0].sign ---+   decimal: | 4 | decimal[0]
   +---+   |    +---+               |            +---+
           |    |   | pV[0].values ------------> | 2 | decimal[1]
           |    +---+               |            +---+
           +--- |   | pV[0].pN      |            | 1 | decimal[2]
                +---+               |            +---+
                |   | pV[1].sign    |
                +---+               |            +---+
                |   | pV[1].values  |      text: |'W'| text[0]
                +---+               |            +---+
                |   | pV[1].pN      |            |'o'| text[1]
                +---+               |            +---+
                                    |            |'r'| text[2]
                                    |            +---+
                                    |            |'d'| text[3]
                                    |            +---+
                                    +----------> |'-'| text[4]
                                                 +---+
                                                 |'2'| text[5]
                                                 +---+
                                                 |'!'| text[6]
                                                 +---+
                                                 | 0 | text[7]
                                                 +---+
```

> `++pV[1].values;`

TL/DR - this sets `pV[1].values` to point to `decimal[2]`.

The expression `++pV[1].values` is parsed as `++(pV[1].values)` - we're adding 1 to `pV[1].values`.  Earlier in the program we copied the contents of `pV[0]` to `pV[1]`, and we had set `pV[0].values` to point to `decimal[1]`.  Like I said above, adding 1 to a pointer yields a pointer to the next object of the pointed-to type; hence, `pV[1].values` now points to `decimal[3]`.

So now our picture looks like this:

```
   +---+        +---+                            +---+
pV:|   | --+--> |   | pV[0].sign ---+   decimal: | 4 | decimal[0]
   +---+   |    +---+               |            +---+
           |    |   | pV[0].values ------------> | 2 | decimal[1]
           |    +---+               |            +---+
           +--- |   | pV[0].pN      |   +------> | 1 | decimal[2]
           |    +---+               |   |        +---+
           |    |   | pV[1].sign ---+   |
           |    +---+               |   |        +---+
           |    |   | pV[1].values -----+  text: |'W'| text[0]
           |    +---+               |            +---+
           +--- |   | pV[1].pN      |            |'o'| text[1]
                +---+               |            +---+
                                    |            |'r'| text[2]
                                    |            +---+
                                    |            |'d'| text[3]
                                    |            +---+
                                    +----------> |'-'| text[4]
                                                 +---+
                                                 |'2'| text[5]
                                                 +---+
                                                 |'!'| text[6]
                                                 +---+
                                                 | 0 | text[7]
                                                 +---+
```

> `++*pV[1].values;`

**TL/DR** - we are incrementing the value of `decimal[3]`.

Similar to the earlier expression, `++*pV[1].values` is parsed as `++(*pV[1].values)`.  Instead of adding 1 to `pV[1].values`, we are adding 1 to the thing `pV[1].values` *points to*, which is `decimal[3]`.  So finally, after everything is said and done, our picture looks like this:

```
   +---+        +---+                            +---+
pV:|   | --+--> |   | pV[0].sign ---+   decimal: | 4 | decimal[0]
   +---+   |    +---+               |            +---+
           |    |   | pV[0].values ------------> | 2 | decimal[1]
           |    +---+               |            +---+
           +--- |   | pV[0].pN      |   +------> | 2 | decimal[2]
           |    +---+               |   |        +---+
           |    |   | pV[1].sign ---+   |
           |    +---+               |   |        +---+
           |    |   | pV[1].values -----+  text: |'W'| text[0]
           |    +---+               |            +---+
           +--- |   | pV[1].pN      |            |'o'| text[1]
                +---+               |            +---+
                                    |            |'r'| text[2]
                                    |            +---+
                                    |            |'d'| text[3]
                                    |            +---+
                                    +----------> |'-'| text[4]
                                                 +---+
                                                 |'2'| text[5]
                                                 +---+
                                                 |'!'| text[6]
                                                 +---+
                                                 | 0 | text[7]
                                                 +---+
```

---

So why do array expressions "decay" into pointer expressions?

C is derived from an earlier programming language named B - in B, when you declared an array, the compiler would set aside a separate word to store the offset to the first element of the array.  Given the declaration

```
auto a[5];
```

you'd have something like this in memory:

```
   +---+
a: |   | ----------+
   +---+           |
    ...            |
   +---+           |
   |   | a[0] <----+
   +---+
   |   | a[1]
   +---+
   |   | a[2]
   +---+
   |   | a[3]
   +---+
   |   | a[4]
   +---+
```

The array subscript operation `a[i]` was defined as `*(a + i)` - given an address stored in `a`, offset `i` words from that address and dereference the result.

Ritchie wanted to keep B's array behavior in C (`a[i] == *(a + i)`), but he didn't want to store the separate pointer that behavior required.  Instead, we have this rule:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3     Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
> unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
> to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
> register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

When you declare an array in C like

```
int a[5];
```

you get this in memory:

```
   +---+
a: |   | a[0]
   +---+
   |   | a[1]
   +---+
   |   | a[2]
   +---+
   |   | a[3]
   +---+
   |   | a[4]
   +---+
```

The array subscript operation `a[i]` is still defined as `*(a + i)`, but instead of storing a pointer value in a separate object named `a`, a pointer value is computed as necessary.  Hence why the expressions `decimal` and `text` ultimately evaluate to pointer values.

Comment: Wow, i feel bad for taking so much of your time. Your explanation and visualisation is really good. Thank you

Comment: now the "++*pV[1].values" makes sense to me. It looked like it had no effect, but we go to the next element by adding +1 and increment the value 1 by 1

Answer (score 0):

> // QUESTION: explanation why decimal + decimal[2] is 2 / what is
> decimal (not *decimal).
> // My guess is: decimal[0 + decimal[2]] =
> decimal[0 + 1] = decimal[1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) = 2

Strictly speaking `decimal + decimal[2]` isn't `2`. It is the pointer, pointing to memory containing `2` (because simple `decimal` points to `decimal[0]`, and adding to this pointer `decimal[2]`, that is `1`, gives us `decimal[1]`, that is `2`).

For the next two questions it is useful to look at [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

```
++pV[1].values; // it's basically ++(pv[1].values), i.e. incrementing of the pointer 'values'
++*pV[1].values; // it's basically ++(*(pv[1].values)), i.e. incrementing of the integer value, pointed by the pointer 'values'
```